# Fixing migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I tried to create a migration to add roles to my user tables but i accidentally typed `AddRolesToUsers` instead of `AddRoleToUser`. So i tried creating a new migration with the correct `AddRoleToUsers` but when i tried to run `rake db:migrate` i got an error :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: role: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "role" integer/Users/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

I tried `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=` do delete the one I had to type on but i keep getting the same error .  PS: i deleted the migration file manually after running `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=`

`rails g migration AddRoleToUsers role:integer`

migration file :

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you display the content of the two migration files?

Comment: Have you run any migrations yet, either the typo one or the new one? I'm basically asking if the :role column has been added to the users table yet or if the migration has just been created

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN i cant run a migrate i keep getting that error

Comment: class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran the first migration, the role column was added to the Users table. The error on the second migration tells you that much.

To clear the `migration pending` error, you need to comment out the `add_column` statement in the new migration. 
i.e,

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end
```

Then run the migration. This way, the new migration should run successfully.

You can now uncomment it and delete the previous migration, so that when you deploy, only the newer migration is run and the `role` column is added successfully.

Comment: @MiguelAngelQuintana You could tick it as answer if it worked, so you'd better guide others. You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

In that case right click and delete both migration files and start again. The error exists because it thinks you want to add two columns both named role to your users table

**UPDATE**

In that case, if role already exists in your users table, a migration must've been successfully run and there is no need to run another. As long as the role column is there, trying to add another column called role will always give you an error. If you wanted to test that you are still able to add new columns you can always check by creating a test migration AddSomethingToUsers something:string and rake db:migrate to test, then rake db:rollback to undo..but it all seems like it's worked so I probably my wouldn't mess with it too much.

Comment: I have done that. First one i had the typo on so i deleted it made another one i got the error once i tried to run `rake db:migrate` and then i tried doing a third one after deleted the first two and the issue is still there.

Comment: Hmm..have a look at your schema..does the role column already exist in the users table? Sorry if you've already checked all this, just trying to rule things out

Comment: the thing is i cant continue doing my Rspec testing cause i get an error saying `/Users/miguel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:392:in `check_pending!':  (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

 bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`